# Is it possible to change subnet in Azure AKS deployment?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I'd like to move an instance of Azure Kubernetes Service to another subnet in the same virtual network. Is it possible or the only way to do this is to recreate the AKS instance?

Comment: What do you mean the AKS instance? the AKS node? or the pod in the AKS?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, it is not possible, you need to redeploy AKS

edit: 08.02.2023 - its actually possible to some extent now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/configure-azure-cni-dynamic-ip-allocation#configure-networking-with-dynamic-allocation-of-ips-and-enhanced-subnet-support---azure-cli

I'm not sure it can be updated on an existing cluster without recreating it (or the nodepool)

Answer (score 3):

I know its an old thread, but just responding in case someone might find it useful. You cannot change the subnet of the AKS directly.  However, you can always change the subnets of the underlying components. In our case, we had a simple setup of 2 nodes and a LoadBalancer. We created a new subnet and change the subnets on these individual components. It worked for us, so do ensure to check the services and the pods, to ensure correct working.

Comment: The only place where I could "update" subnet was on "kubernetes-internal" private load balancer. So I would gladly see how you change subnet references on VMSS with Azure CNI in place. Do you have a working solution on GitHub and you could share the code?

Comment: It was not an automated one or with use of any powershell. It was more of a manual exercise to create new subnets, go to the individual NICs and change the Subnet on them. It works well for a small cluster, but for a larger cluster it would be very cumbersome. Again we had not used VMSS. So I have not tried with VMSS.